# Does there exist isolated environment or virtual environment like pyvenv for bash/zsh sessions?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

I want to test certain cli applications which I want to install only in the isolated environment and has no impact over the rest of the system.

Comment: It kinda depends on the level of isolation you need. Create a temporary directory in your home directory, start a new shell in it with `env -i HOME=$HOME/tmpdir bash`, install the software there and run, the `exit` and remove the directory, or use a chroot directory, or use a Docker container, or use Vagrant to spin up a virtual machine. Run the thing in it. Remove the VM. There is no indication of what you mean by "isolation", or "impact" for that matter (is using disk space ok?).  It's not as if stuff running in pyenv can't affect the rest of the system.

Comment: Google: firejail.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options (non-exhaustive list):

1. VM (Qemu/KVM, Xen, VirtualBox, VMware...) - the most isolated (bar separate hardware system). Unless you want to spend a little bit of extra effort on it, you'll be running a separate OS installation. It is possible to reuse your current system in a non-destructive way though e.g. by telling the VM to use a disk image backed by your main (host) system image - that would then mean that any changes the guest system decided to make would go the "upper level" image, while the underlying host image (typically partitions on your hard drive) would stay intact.
2. [system-level virtualisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-level_virtualization#Implementations) using some kind of container - less secure by design, lighter on system (read: hardware) resources. Generally you would be sharing the same running kernel with the containerized system, which is exactly where it becomes less secure - a malicious application using a vulnerability in the kernel will not be isolated from your main system. As usually, there are several options. For Linux the classical examples are:

   1. `chroot` - a separate directory which is to become the root (`/`) directory for a new process. Which means it needs to contain all possible libraries and binaries (and configuration/data/...) that will be needed. From security point of view it is [broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot#Limitations), but is present pretty much on any system.
   2. [`firejail`](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) - "chroot on steroids" (I prefer to think about it as "chroot as it should be"). Works in a similar way with additional restrictions and supporting features. Namely it allows one to easily mount particular parts of the existing filesystem structure into the target environment with varying access rights, while it still resembles the original environment structure. On top of that, `firejail` allows to choose what system calls will be allowed in its container
3. "user-level" virtualisation - create another user account and run the application as that user. Security-wise relying on system access controls only. Easiest to set up.